# how the functioality handled by viewstate is handled in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I came to know there is no viewstate in MVC.

I have two question with respect to view state.

first question:

In classic web forms Viewstate is used to maintain control states during round trips. even i am not clear with this point. I read somewhere like if i disable viewstate in a page all the forms controls will be cleared after postback. I don't feel this is a valid reason for the need of a viewstate. The ASP.net engine could handle this situation (mainatianing state) without viewstate.

and my second question: which part of MVC is handling view state responsibility.

Regards,
Ramana Akula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewState is not needed because there are no server-side controls (at least there shouldn't be).

Simple as that really.

Server-side controls use ViewState to track (in some cases all) property values that need to be restored when the page is posted back.  Equally, it's the mechanism by which server-side events such as `TextChanged` can be fired - the server re-hydrates the `asp:TextBox`'s `Text` value as it was when the ViewState was saved into the page, and compares it to the value that is POSTed back - if it's different, the event is fired.  For example.

In truth ViewState is a very clever solution...  But I have to say I loathe it.

In MVC, when a text-box is rendered (or, should I say, an HTML input `type=text`) and then submitted back, it's value is re-bound back from the request.  On the server you then reconstitute the data you need to compose the view again.

I've written quite a few MVC sites now - and I've not even had a need to switch on session state yet.

If you're coming from Asp.Net Forms it can be totally mind-boggling at first (it really depends on how comfortable you are with HTML in general), but ultimately it's incredibly liberating; and obviously makes a huge difference with performance.

Comment: so, the only reason for view state is server controls. could you help me in understanding why server controls need view state ?

Comment: that's outside a simple answer on SO - especially when the information is already out there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

:)

Answer (score 0):

Got the point. my conception was wrong.

view state is used to re construct the server side control properties with valid data. Relevent functionality is handled by model binding in MVC.